# How to make mode-line text look like a link/button on hover

Tags: mode-line, faces, text-properties, mouse

What face/text/other property should I use to have mode-line text look like a button/link/stuff to click on while I am hovering over it with the cursor?

Some examples:

- different background,
- 3D-like button decoration,
- colorful frame/border displayed around it
- other visual cues would be fine as well (as I don't know what choices are avaliable).

Otherwise it should just look like any ordinary text.

Below is a fragment of my custom mode-line which I'd like to enhance:

```
(setq mode-line-format
   (list
     (propertize
      (concat "[" (propertize "f" 'face 'aria2-modeline-key-face) "]:add file")
      'local-map (make-mode-line-mouse-map 'mouse-1 'aria2-add-file)) " "
     ;; [...]
```

PS: Is there some list of available text properties (for header/mode-line, buffer, frame border etc.) and their meanings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `mouse-face` property.

For example, the following snippet will make "f" look like a button when you hover the mouse pointer over it:

```
(setq mode-line-format
   (list
     (propertize
      (concat "[" (propertize "f" 'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight) "]:add file")
      'local-map (make-mode-line-mouse-map 'mouse-1 'aria2-add-file)) " "))
```

Answer (score 2):

Face `button` or face `link`.  Use `M-x list-faces-display` to see all faces currently defined.

(That said, I personally think that the standard behavior is not bad: mouseover to see whether a particular part of the mode line is a link/button and whether it has a menu etc.)